# Java variable in URL not working

Tags: java

So basically i have a script that's downloading a txt file contents off a website. It works but i wanted to add variables to the link so it's custom to each user. So just as an example i wanted it to be like:

```
String name = "Matt";
String URLComplete = "http://www.domain.com/" + name + "/test.txt";
URL url = new URL(URLComplete);
```

That doesn't work but if i did

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.domain.com/Matt/test.txt");
```

It would work, i don't understand what i'm doing wrong?

---

So even if i do the following:

```
String URLComplete = "http://www.domain.com/name/test.txt";
```

URL url = new URL(URLComplete);

It doesn't work but if i do

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.domain.com/name/test.txt");
```

It will work, by work i mean it successfully reads/downloads in the string/array from the website. I've outputted both and the urls are identical no mistakes i've visited both through my browser and i end up at the correct page.

---

Full Code:

This is my full code of retrieving the data.

```
public class Retrieve {


    public static List<String> getWhitelist()
    {
        try
        {

            String name = "Matt";
            String URLComplete = "http://www.domain.com/" + name + "/test.txt";

            List<String> strings = new ArrayList();
            URL url = new URL(URLComplete);
            BufferedReader urlReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String s;
            while ((s = urlReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                strings.add(s);
            }
            return strings;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }


    public static String downloadString(String link)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            BufferedReader result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            return result.readLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        return "Unable to connect to the internet!";
    }



}
```

Comment: How did you come to know that first one is not working?

Comment: As @TAsk is asking, you should also include in your question all errors you've encountered along with the things you have tried so far to fix the problem. As an initial guess though, are there any non url safe characters in those `names`? Spaces, punctuation, many utf8 chars etc can not be part of valid URLs.

Comment: No output, where as if i just set the URL there is an output, both urls are identical.

Comment: Can you share more of the surrounding code? Have a quick read of: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Crafting a small example separated from your problem code/project can often lead you to a solution and in almost all instances, makes it easier (and faster) for people to help you.

Comment: And there must be some output. Either a 404 as the URL you are trying to access cannot be found, a URL parsing exception if the String url is not a valid URL or something. Fetching a remote resource should not fail silently.

Comment: I added my full-code below.

Comment: The biggest thing that jumps out to me there is that you are catching `Exception` (which is in itself a bad idea almost always) but you are not logging anything! That is part of what I was referring to above when talking about "not failing silently". You should at a minimum add `e.printStackTrace()` to that catch block and then you might see what's going wrong for you.

Comment: Got it working in the end using:

`URL url = new URL("http", "domain.com", "/" + name + "/test.txt");`

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this following the below example

```
    URL gamelan = new URL("http", "example.com", 80, "pages/page1.html");
```

which is equivalent to

```
   http://example.com:80/pages/page1.html
```

for more examples click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/creatingUrls.html)

Comment: I looked through the page you recommend and got it working in the end using:

`URL url = new URL("http", "domain.com", "/" + name + "/test.txt");`

Thanks so much for the help.